# Is it possible to set a Object.defineProperty() on this.var in a class

Tags: javascript

So I have created a class Complex with the following constructor and methods

```
class Komplex {
  constructor(real, imag) {
    if (real === undefined && imag === undefined) {
      real = 0
      imag = 0
      this.real = real
      this.imag = imag
    } else if (imag === undefined) {
      this.real = real
      this.imag = 0
    } else if (typeof real === "number" && typeof imag === "number") {
      this.real = real
      this.imag = imag
    } else {
      real = 0
      imag = 0
      this.real = real
      this.imag = imag
    }
  }
}
```

So my question would be how do I make "this.real" and "this.imag" not writeable with Object.defineProperty(); ?

Comment: `this#real = stuff` (private properties, they are close to being specified)

Comment: You could simplify that by using [default function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):
  `constructor(real = 0, imag = 0) {
    this.real = real;
    this.imag = imag;
  }
`

Comment: At the very least: `this.real = typeof real == 'number' ? real : 0;`. Same for `imag`…

Comment: @lealceldeiro in my assignment its specifically says to use Object.defineproperty for the variables after giving them a value

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(this, 'real', { value: real})` ?

Comment: *I have created a class Complex* ... fail ... `class Komplex`

Comment: `class Komplex {
  constructor(real, imag) {
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      real: {
        value: real || 0
      },
      imag: {
        value: imag || 0
      }
    });
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.defineProperties` (to define multiple properties at once) with `this`. The `writable` property defines whether the defined property in the target object is only readable or not and it defaults to `false`

See also docs on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties):

> **`writable`**
>
> `true` if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed with an assignment operator.
>
> Defaults to `false`.

```js
class Komplex {
  constructor(real, imag) {
    if (real === undefined && imag === undefined) {
      real = 0
      imag = 0
    } else if (imag === undefined) {
      imag = 0
    } else if (typeof real !== "number" || typeof imag !== "number") {
      real = 0
      imag = 0
    }

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      real: {
        value: real
      },
      imag: {
        value: imag
      }
    });
  }
}


(function() {
  'use strict';

  let val = new Komplex(1, 2);
  val.real = 5;
})();
```